# React AddItem to list in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use `AddItem` to add items to a list in another component. However, I keep getting `undefined`.

How do I correctly add an item to a list?

I've put it inside a CodeSandbox too: https://codesandbox.io/s/Mjjrm3zrO

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: [x.movies],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CreateNew addItem={item => this.setState({ movie: [item].concat(this.state.movie) })} />
          {x.movies.map(movie => (
            <Result key={movie.id} result={movie} addItem={item => this.setState({ genres: [item].concat(this.state.genres) })} />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class CreateNew extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      genres: '',
    };
  }
  handleSubmit1 = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addItem(this.state.value)
    console.log(this.props.item);
  };
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: {'name': e.target.value}, genres: [{ name: 'Test', type: 1 }, { name: 'Foo', type: 10 }] });
    console.log(this.state.value);
  };
  render() {
    const { value, genres } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit1}>
        Add a new movie
        <input onChange={this.onChange} type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class Result extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { result } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <li>
          {result.name} {' '}
          ({result.genres.map(x => x.name).join(', ')}){' '}
        </li>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** Instead of sending only name from child component send the whole state variable that will contain name and genres.

```
handleSubmit1 = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addItem(this.state)
};
```

**2.** You are storing the initial value movies from json to state variable so use that state variable to create the ui, because you are updating the state variable once you adding any new item, so if you use initial json to create ui then new item will not reflect in ui.

```
{this.state.movies.map(movie => (
    <Result key={movie.id} result={movie} />
))}
```

**3.** Update the `state` variable movies like this:

```
<CreateNew addItem={item => this.setState({ movies: [{name: item.value.name, genres: item.genres}].concat(this.state.movies) })} />
```

Check the working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/3nD0RgRp